# Alpha blending for background

Tags: directx, textures, transparency

I am a beginner to DirectX, so please keep it simple for me. I have loaded a texture and displayed it on a quad, but the transparent background still shows. How can I stop that? I have tried a couple different ways, and they stopped it from showing, but the other quads I drew to the screen disappeared as well (they were not textured).

Comment: I tried to polish my crystal ball, but it doen't help. Please give some additional information about your problem, especially some pieces of code, where you assume your errors (drawcall, setup of the vertices). The first guess if transparency isn't working: Have you set the renderstate for alphablending to true?

Comment: I could get the alpha to work, but all rectangles without a texture would no longer show up. I think I understand why XNA required a texture to draw a rectangle now. Perhaps this is a limitation of DirectX?

Comment: There are no restrictions like that, it depends all on your vertexformat and drawing code. Did you set the alpha-value in your vertexcolor?

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I had to do set the drawing texture to null after drawing a textured quad.

Comment: Can you answer your question yourself and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not reset the texture to null before drawing primitives that did not have a texture.